# How to reset form in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

In the end of my page, before closing `body`, I have this code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {    
    for (var i = 0, form; form = document.forms[i]; ++i)
        form.reset();
}
```

But it doesn't work... It executed, but noting happens... Form still is filled, but when i run same code from firebug it works fine! I also tried wrap code with `jQuery(document).ready()` function but still no luck... It works only from firebug console...

**UPDATE:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('store_user') }}" autocomplete="off">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="margin-bottom:5px">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: I think the intention is to clear the auto-filled fields which probably triggers after the full page load including the onready() is run

Comment: @Teemu FF autofills the form which  creates a new user with my saved data (username and password) when page is loaded.

Comment: @GordonMacDonald I tried `jQuery(document).ready` - still autofill works.

Comment: @user1692333 - have you tried adding that attribute autocomplete="false" to the form? that will turn off the autocomplete for the form completely and you can remove your javascript to do the same

Comment: @Teemu It is set to the form and also for each field

Comment: @user1692333 can you update the question showing the form code?

Comment: @user1692333 - you may want to clear your browser or shift-reload to properly clear any older cached version too...

Comment: @GordonMacDonald added.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to prevent the form being auto-completed in Firefox (an annoying feature) then simply mark the form as autocomplete "off"

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
```

Also check out this document:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

particularly the section where it says if the autocomplete still persists to try:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Since this random value is not a valid one, the browser will give up.

Comment: Stupid FF ignores it for a log time.

Comment: Nope, no luck. Still see my email and password in the form when it should be empty.

Comment: aren't you setting the values for both those fields in the html:value="{{ old('email') }}"  - can you blank those value settings?

Comment: This values appear when new user is created. In the form appears my own login values. But ok, removed it that it not be so confusing.

Comment: sorry to ask but can you try two things: 1) try clearing you cache and then doing a shift-f5 to reload to make sure nothings cached 2) can you try setting autocomplete to "nope" as decscribed in the link in my answer

Comment: Note that the shortcut is [Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+F5](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation), not Shift+F5.